# Como separar código de Texto

Tags: microsoft-excel

Oi pessoa boa tarde tudo bem?

Tenho uma dúvida que gostaria de saber se podem me auxiliar, por favor:

Tenho um arquivo .txt , no qual contém mais de 1000 linhas, preciso separar o código do texto.... me explico melhor com o exemplo :

```
CO123456= texto1      (Primeira Linha )
CO123457= texto2      (Segunda Linha )    
CO123458= texto3      (Terceira Linha )
```

preciso eliminar ( `CO123456=`, `CO123457=` e `CO123458=`) ou seja ficar
`texto1`, `texto2` e `texto3` .... ficando assim :

```
texto1      (Primeira Linha )
texto2      (Segunda Linha )    
texto3      (Terceira Linha )
```

Tentei realizar isto com modo " Substituir " no Excel só que não consegui... devido que tinha umas linhas que tinham muitos sinais de igual (=) , desta forma eliminava a frase toda.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Acho que com regex da certo, não sei se no notepad suporta replace com regex, mas acredito que isso resolve: `CO[0-9]{6}= ?` Isso presumindo que todos os codigos comecem com CO seguidos por 6 numeros

Comment: Se a sua pergunta é sobre o uso do Notepad++, eu sinto lhe informar que este site não é o local adequado para postá-la. Se, por outro lado, você escreveu um código em VBA (ou mesmo usa algumas funções em Excel) para fazer isso, a pergunta já fica dentro do escopo. Apesar de você já ter uma resposta potencialmente útil (para uso no Excel), eu votei para fechar como fora do escopo porque acho que a sua pergunta está mais no primeiro sentido. Edite-a e melhore, removendo a referência ao Notepad++ se for o caso de a sua intenção ser mesmo usar o Excel.

Comment: Você pode abrir o seu txt pelo Excel e definir os delimitadores da coluna de vários tipos diferentes, como por exemplo tabulação (TAB), espaços, sinal de igualdade ou até mesmo um delimitador fixo. Me parece ser a melhor opção. Dá uma olhada nesse link aqui que ele ilustra o que eu disse acima: http://www.dhlebilling.com.br/ebilling/do/LinkExterno/importTxtExel

Answer (score 2):

Se você possui um padrão para o código, aonde você sempre vai ter que remover o código composto de 9 caracteres, um símbolo de igualdade e um espaço, você pode usar o seguinte código

```
=RIGHT(A1; LEN(A1)-10)
```

**Explicando:**

`A1` - Célula na qual será aplicada a regra.

`LEN(A1)-10` - Busca o tamanho da célula (no caso A1), e subtrai uma quantidade x de caracteres (no caso 10).

Agora basta aplicar essa fórmula para todas as suas células. Acredito que esse será o menor dos problemas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Leonardo, boa tarde ! 
Estou tentando realizar no Excel..... a seguinte formula e da erro:

=right (A1; LEN (A1)-10)

Diz : Encontramos um problema na formula....

Comment: Poderia postar um pedaço do arquivo para eu realizar alguns testes?

Comment: CO000060690=%d de %d correspondência
CO000060691=%d de %d correspondências
CO000060692=%s "%d" não reconhecido.

Comment: E você precisa que fique apenas o %d de %d correspondência ?

Comment: Preciso sim!
Todo o texto que vem depois de = ( sinal de igual) serve .

Comment: @RodrigoHackzExploitz adicionei uma imagem, seria esse o resultado esperado?

Comment: Sim, exatamente seria isso.... perfeito...mais como vc fez???

Comment: Utilizei esse código aí que eu tinha postado. Tenta escrever ele ao invés de copiar inclusive os espaços. Talvez dê certo.

Answer (score -4):

```
Sub sbx_separar_dados()
Dim wLin As Integer, wLoca As Integer, wBusca As String
For i = 2 To Planilha1.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    wLen = Len(Cells(i, "a"))
    wLoca = InStr(1, Cells(i, "a"), "=") + 1
    wBusca = Mid(Cells(i, "a"), wLoca, wLen)
    Cells(i, "c") = wBusca
Next i
End Sub

Sub sbx_separar_dados_limpar()
Dim wLin As Integer, wLoca As Integer, wBusca As String
wLin = Planilha1.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Planilha1.Range("C2:C" & wLin).ClearContents
End Sub
```